# Odd behaviour (row skipping) of view-based NSTableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to create a single column view-based NSTableview in Cocoa. I want the first row of the table to be a group row and I subclassed NSTableRowView to create a transparent group row.
So far so good. I then want the second row to be a custom cell with some content. The third row should be instead a group row again (indicating the start of a new section).

Here is the code of the delegate methods of my tableview:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row 
{
    if ((row == 0) || (row == 2)) return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    TransparentGroupRowView *rowView = [[TransparentGroupRowView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    return rowView;    
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row 
{
    if (row == 0) {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"headerCell" owner:self];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = @"Propagation Dimension";
        return cellView;
    } else if (row == 1) {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"propagationDimensionCell" owner:self];
        if (self.geometry.propagationDimension) cellView.textField.stringValue = self.geometry.propagationDimension;
        return cellView;
    } else if (row == 2) {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"headerCell" owner:self];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = @"Transverse Dimensions";
        return cellView;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the result is that the first row is drawn on top of the second. Instead of the first row I get an empty space. 
Here is an even odder behaviour. If I return NO for the method isGroupRow for the first row, it displays in its correct position but obviously it looks different from what I want.

It almost seems to me a pointer issue but I can't see where the problem is.

[image: As you see transverse dimension is displayed correctly with a transparent background. Propagation dimension is drawn instead on top of the second row (grey). The blank space on top is where the first group row (propagation dimension) should be.]

As you see transverse dimension is displayed correctly with a transparent background. Propagation dimension is drawn instead on top of the second row (grey). The blank space on top is where the first group row (propagation dimension) should be.

Comment: It is a little hard to follow without visuals.. you you mind including some screenshots?

Comment: You are right, my apologies. Picture uploaded